# Using immutability-helper's `$splice` on an array in React is making the whole list to be deleted

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to implement a simple way to exclude an item from the state array by giving the index.

This is the following:

```
  import update from 'immutability-helper'

  // ...

  const { params } = this.state

  let index = _.findIndex(params.certificates, { instructions: instructions })

  this.setState({
    params: update(params.certificates, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
  })
```

But what is happening is the whole `params.certificate` to be deleted. But I logged out `index` and it's correctly display the index of the item I clicked.

Comment: What's that `update` function?

Comment: @klaasman the syntax seems to be similar to immutability-helper npm package

Comment: Ok. Right after I posted, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason, using `update` inside of `setState` caused this. This is the way I found to solve it:

```
  const { params } = this.state

  let index = _.findIndex(params.certificates, { instructions: instructions })
  let certificates = update(params.certificates, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})

  this.setState({ params: { certificates }  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If `params` have multiple other things apart from `certificates` , in that case you should use `update` function like

```
const { params } = this.state
     let index = _.findIndex(params.certificates, { instructions: instructions })
   this.setState({
    params: update(params, { certificates: {$splice: [[index, 1]]}})
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have done it this way:

```
const { params } = this.state

  let index = _.findIndex(params.certificates, { instructions: instructions });
  const spliced = { $splice: [[index, 1]] };

  this.setState({
     params: update(params.certificates, spliced)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the `update()` function return the certificates and not the params object.

In you example you're basically doing `setState({ params: certificates })` overwriting the whole param object with the certificates.

One way to correct this would be to do this : 
`setState({ params: { certificates: update(......)}})`

But i also prefer your solution of spliting `setState` and `update` call, i find it a lot more clear.

```
const { params } = this.state

  let index = _.findIndex(params.certificates, { instructions: instructions })
  let certificates = update(params.certificates, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})

  this.setState({ params: { certificates }  })
```